# Ruby: Transform a string of time to xsd:datetime conforming string?

Tags: ruby, xml, xsd

I have this: "2013-02-23 18:06:00 UTC"

and need this: "2013-02-23T18:06:00Z"

to conform to this: http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77049.html

Does anyone know of a good library/tool/method in Ruby to do this without having to write some transformation method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the rubydocs for `Datetime` [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html). There's a method to convert into ISO8601.

Comment: Ah, jeeze, I've even used that library before. Haha, thanks very much.

Comment: Don't forget to convert to UTC if not already in UTC... `mydatetime.utc.iso8601`

Answer (score 2):

Within Rails:

```
DateTime.now.utc.strftime()
=> "2012-08-22T17:55:12+00:00"
```